# Bootstrap Table - Move cell to the right to properly display the total

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Good evening, I'm trying to align a table to make it like the picture, but failed to do so, I could help?

Now I have it like this:

[image: table_now]
and I'd like it to look like this:
[image: Table]

This is my html code:

```html
<table class="table table-hover table-bordered">
   <thead>
     <tr>
       <th class="text-left">Codigo</th>
       <th class="text-left">Descripcion</th>
       <th class="text-left">Precio</th>
       <th class="text-left">Cantidad</th>
       <th class="text-left">Importe</th>
     </tr>
   </thead>
   <tbody>
     <tr>
       <td class="col-md-1">1001</td>
       <td class="col-md-8">Producto de ejemplo 1</td>
       <td class="col-md-1 text-right">$10,000</td>
       <td class="col-md-1 text-center">100</td>
       <td class="col-md-1 text-right">$1,000,000</td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
       <th class="text-right" scope="row">TOTAL</th>
       <td class="text-right">$1,000,000</td>
     </tr>
   </tbody>
 </table>
```

Comment: Need more information to isolate specific problem. Do you have your css as well? How about a picture of how it looks for you?

Comment: @Mogsdad Add the information requested, greetings and thanks.

Comment: Without the css, it's not possible to identify the proper `class` for cells that should have no borders.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Specifying the `colspan` for the cells in the summary row will shift the final cell right.

```
<th colspan="4" class="text-right" scope="row">TOTAL</th>
```

Alternatively, you could start the row with a `<td>` with `colspan="3"`, and using a `class` that would have no borders (controlled by your css).

```
<td colspan="3" class="noborders"></td>
<th class="text-right" scope="row">TOTAL</th>
```

Without that `class`, direct manipulation of `style` may work.

```
<td style="border:0" colspan="3"></td>
<th class="text-right" scope="row">TOTAL</th>
```

#### Updated snippet:

```css
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  font-family: arial;
}

td,
th {
  width: auto;
  margin: 2px;
  padding: 3px;
  text-align: left;
  border: 1px solid grey;
}

.noborders {
  border: 0;
}

.text-left {
  text-align: left;
}

.text-center {
  text-align: center;
}

.text-right {
  text-align: right;
}
```

```html
<table class="table table-hover table-bordered">
   <thead>
     <tr>
       <th class="text-left">Codigo</th>
       <th class="text-left">Descripcion</th>
       <th class="text-left">Precio</th>
       <th class="text-left">Cantidad</th>
       <th class="text-left">Importe</th>
     </tr>
   </thead>
   <tbody>
     <tr>
       <td class="col-md-1">1001</td>
       <td class="col-md-8">Producto de ejemplo 1</td>
       <td class="col-md-1 text-right">$10,000</td>
       <td class="col-md-1 text-center">100</td>
       <td class="col-md-1 text-right">$1,000,000</td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
       <td colspan="3" class="noborders"></td>
       <th class="text-right" scope="row">TOTAL</th>
       <td class="text-right">$1,000,000</td>
     </tr>
   </tbody>
 </table>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I want to use "ha" as this convina cells and is not the result I expect, any other ideas?

Comment: With the exception of CSS padding problems that hide some borders (since you didn't provide the css), this is exactly the result you asked for. Maybe your question needs to be more specific.

Comment: Thank you very much, gave me the idea of adding an empty cell with: colspan="3"